# Where to get hardware model data?

Tags: modeling, formal-languages, formal-methods

I have a task which consists of 3 concurrent self-defined (recursive to each other) processes. I need somehow to make it execute on computer, but any attempt to convert a requirement to program code with just my brain fails since first iteration produces 3^3 entities with 27^2 cross-relations, but it needs to implement at least several iterations to try if program even works at all.

So I decided to give up on trying to understand the whole system and [formalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) the problem and now want to **map** it to hardware to generate an algorithm and run. Language doesn't matter (maybe even directly to machine/assembly one?).

I never did anything like that before, so all topics I searched through like [algorithm synthesis](http://www.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_2335/2004-02-18-A.pdf), [software and hardware co-design](https://embedded.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/hsc/abstract.html), etc. mention **hardware model** as the second half (in addition to **problem model**) of solution generation, but I never seen one. The whole work supposed to look like this:
[image]

I don't know yet what *level* **hardware model** described at, so can't decide how **problem model** must be formalized to fit hardware model layer.
For example, target system may contain CPU and GPGPU, let's say target solution having 2 concurrent processes. System must decide which process to run on CPU and which on GPGPU. The highest level solution may come from comparing computational intensity of processes with target hardware, which is [~300 for CPUs](http://ithare.com/infographics-operation-costs-in-cpu-clock-cycles/) and [~50 for GPGPUs](https://books.google.ru/books?id=wcS_DAAAQBAJ).
But a normal model gotta be much more complete with at least **cache hierarchy**, **memory access batch size**, etc.
Another example is implementing [k-ary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree). A synthesized algorithm could address parents and children with computing `k * i + c` / `( i - 1 ) / k` **or** store direct pointers - depending on `computations per memory latency` ratio.

Where can I get a hardware model or data to use? Any hardware would suffice for now - to just see how it can look like - later would be awesome to get models of modern processors, GPGPUs and common heterogeneous clusters.
Do manufacturers supply such kinds of models? Description of how their systems work in any formal language.

Comment: I do not understand why half of viewers voted to close() the question because it's not about programming. From Wikipedia: **Programming is the process of creating a set of instructions that tell a computer how to perform a task.** I want to generate (==create) a set of instructions using formal methods which involves modeling. For that I need hardware model and looking for it. Leaving comments about why someone puts question to close() would be productive - I could improve my question.

Comment: I think it might be because people think that the question is not about how to generate such set of instructions, but about a recommendation of a hardware, which in most cases are subjective.
But this one seems more objective, but I do not understand the topic well enough to speak more about that. (I didn't vote to close)
Maybe you can emphasis the main question? (is it the first question in second paragraph?) Also maybe more details will help (I do not understand what kind of model you are looking for, but it might be because I lack expertise on this)

Comment: @justhalf edited my question. Thanks for advices ;)

Comment: You will probably be able to find overviews of various *computer architectures*, including network/cluster topologies, etc., but I doubt you're going to find it in a consistent and common formalized notation. Something like that could clearly be helpful for the reasons you point out; however, if you find (as I suspect you will) that it doesn't exist, the reason may be that optimizing at the level of the hardware architecture is typically not required or, in any case, a last resort. Computations that need that kind of performance optimization may require human-equivalent input for fine tuning.

Comment: @Patrick87 thank you for comment. The thing is that I actually have NO algorithm - it's too complicated for me to write it. I'm implementing deductive system which tries to solve a problem by searching a set of operations which fit into defined constraints and chooses the best solution if there are multiple. For now, all operations defined I have is **access memory** and **multiply/sum** which characteristic I took from WWW for my processor I'm currently building to - that's too bad :(

Comment: Question seems to be in the wrong community and sounds very ambiguous. Did you check other Stack Exchange communities like https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ or https://cs.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @AivarasPrudnikovas thank you, I'll try do that.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno it IS about programming. Please refer to my first commentary. Term **model** here is used regarding description, not "specific instance", I had to clarify it from the first place, my bad. Basically, to write a program you need to know what computer does. To write concurrent lock-less program you need specifically know HOW computer does things. So the question is **how and where you know about how computer does things** ... again, **to write a program**.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not pretty sure if it might be the case for you, but as you're mentioning modeling, I just thought about [Modelica](https://www.modelica.org/). It's used to model physical systems and combined with a simulation environment, you can run some simulations on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I know, Modelica is modeling and simulation framework, but modeling is already performed for my problem. The problem is I can't find **data** to configure a model in such a way that it would reflect hardware. The weird part is that any complex system like processor **is** made with first modeling it with at least SysML, ECLiPSe, etc., so such definitely should exist, but not released? IBM even has [it's own modeling framework](https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/dept/vst/csp.shtml) with [free version](https://www.ibm.com/bs-en/marketplace/ibm-ilog-cplex).